# arraymap vs foreach loop when creating a comma delimited string

Tags: php

I'm creating a comma delimited string for an SQL query. I would like to know what is better arraymap or a foreach loop. Here are my two examples:

```
$group_ids = "";
foreach ($group_array as $group_id) {
    $group_ids .= $group_id . ",";
}
$group_ids = rtrim($group_ids, ',');
```

vs

```
$group_ids = "";
array_map(function ($group_id) use ($group_ids) {
    $group_ids .= $group_id . ",";
    return;
}, $group_array);
$group_ids = rtrim($group_ids, ',');
```

Or is there a better way? Or is there literally not much difference?

Comment: `Array_map()` is slower than `foreach()`

Comment: Using a prepared statement placeholders (`rtrim(str_repeat('?,', count($group_array)), ',')`) and then executing the query with $group_array as an array of arguments for binding is even better

Answer (score 4):

```
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);
```

from 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

would be more efficient

Comment: But *is it* more efficient?

Comment: In terms of the code, it's easier to follow. Why overcomplicate things? In terms of performance, any difference will be measured in microseconds I expect.

Comment: from what i can gather across the interblargs, implode would be the winner by at LEAST 1ms, if you need to arraymap to clean your data, then use array_walk and get on with your life @Sed

Comment: @ProEvilz From the theoretical point of view, it is **much more** efficient. It's only one C function call vs. a lot of interpreted code (the `foreach` version) or, even worse, a lot of PHP function calls (the `array_map()` version). Even more, `implode()` internally generates only one string of the final size and copies into it the values of the array. The other versions do a lot of string allocations, copying and deallocations. From the practical point of view, if the array doesn't contain thousands of items, the difference is negligible. But the code is much cleaner using `implode()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `implode(',',$array_of_ids)`. Just make sure you trim your values before using the implode.

```
$ids = ['foo','bar','boo'];
$ids = array_map('trim',$ids);
$ids_list = implode(',',$ids);
echo $ids_list; # foo,bar,boo
```

Comment: While the call to `trim()` is useful to produce a nice string, it doesn't add any value in this context. If the string generated this way is used to construct a `IN (...)` fragment of an SQL query, the whitespace do not matter. But with or without `trim()`, the answer is correct, nevertheless.